Open url using auto_execok at anchor points
I cannot open a url at an anchor point using auto_execok, on windows 11. On Linux, everything works as expected.
More specifically, I have a url that I want my code to open a browser to. To do this, I use auto_execok as follows:
set url "mylocalfile.html#anchor1"
set command [list {*}[auto_execok start] {}]
exec {*}$command $url 

On windows 11, this results in a browser opening at mylocalfile.html, i.e. the anchor is omitted.
On Linux, the exact same results in opening the appropriate page, pointing at the anchor point.

I wonder what is chewing up the anchor...

Yes, me too.. I've tried protecting the hash character, this does not seem to be it.
